# Why is not memory being allocated properly to my char* in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory

To be honest I have no idea what to write as the title. The problem that I am facing is that once I allocate the memory to char* line in LinkedList struct it seems to shrink to 26 in the next iteration. I haven't written complete code (only the part that I think is relevant). fileRead_runner is a thread run method and what it does is that searches for lines with particular keyword and sends back to parent in the form of linked list. I intend to do that with char* line in LinkedList struct but I am facing some mysterious problem. I have given the sample output. "out: number" is the real size of the string and the number on the next line is what length program stores.

Any help will be appreciated! 
Thanks!

```
struct LinkedList{
    char* line;
    struct LinkedList* next;
};
struct  Node{
    char *keyword;
    char* fileName;
    struct LinkedList* head;
};
    void* fileRead_runner(void* args){
        struct Node* node = (struct Node*)args;
        FILE* fp;
        char* out;
        node->head = malloc(sizeof(char*)+sizeof(struct LinkedList*));
        struct LinkedList* curr;
        curr = node->head;
        fp = fopen(node->fileName, "r");
        int lineNum = 1;
        char line[512];
        int found;
        int first = 0;
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL){
            found = 0;
            char* temp = malloc(sizeof(line));
            strcpy(temp, line);
            char* token = strtok(temp, " \t\n");
            while(token != NULL && found == 0){
                if(strcmp(token, node->keyword) == 0){
                    found = 1;
                }
                token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
            }
            if(found == 1){
                out = malloc(sizeof(line));
                char* num = malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
                snprintf(num, sizeof(num), "%d: ", lineNum);
                strcpy(out, node->fileName);
                strcat(out, ", ");
                strcat(out, num);
                strcat(out, line);
                if(first != 0){
                    curr->next = malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList*));
                    printf("%d\n", strlen(curr->line));
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
                curr->line = malloc(sizeof(out));
                strcpy(curr->line, out);
                first = 1;
                //curr->next = NULL;
                printf("out: %d\n", strlen(curr->line));
            }
            lineNum++;
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
out: 202
26
out: 18
18
out: 94
26
out: 155
26
out: 242
26
out: 96
26
out: 27
26
out: 133
26
out: 25
26
out: 93
26
out: 35
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            curr->line = malloc(sizeof(out));
```

Since `out` is a `char *`, this allocated a number of bytes for `curr->line` equal to how many bytes a pointer takes. That makes no sense. Maybe you want:

```
            curr->line = malloc(strlen(out) + 1);
```

This allocates enough space to store the string and a zero character to mark its end.

Comment: I knew I would be making silliest mistake. I have just started using C so I am getting use to it. Thanks for the help. Btw do you know if I can change the tiltle as it seems misleading?

Comment: @Mustafa For what it's worth, if you allocate a buffer as David explained and then use `strcpy` to copy a string to it, you might want to consider using the `strdup` function which does both things in one go.

Comment: Thanks for your input @FrerichRaabe. Appreiated! It makes my code more concise now.